# Tablelayoutpanel scrolls to bottom after loading c# winforms

Tags: c#, scroll, tablelayoutpanel

I created a windows form page with a tableLayoutPanel docked to the top and a panel docked to the bottom.  The tablelayoutPanel is has scrolling enabled.  When the form loads the bottom of the the table layout panel is shown first.  Is there a way to show the top of the tablepanellayout?

Document Outline

1. dialogCreateAccount: FormDialogBase
2. tblAccount tableLayoutPanel
3. PanelActions Panel
4. BtnSave
5. BtnClose

Screenshot shows the bottom of the table panel is shown first to the user.
[[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wire up the `Shown()` event of the Form, and then use [ScrollControlIntoView()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview?view=net-5.0).

For example, if `label1` was at the top of your TableLayoutPanel, then:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.ScrollControlIntoView(label1);
```